# РазобрАла или разобралА?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: разобрАла или разобралА?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно ставить ударение на окончание: **разобралА**.

> Ударение в формах прошедшего времени глаголов: у большинства глаголов в формах женского рода ударение падает на окончание -а. В формах
>   мужского, среднего рода и во множественном числе — на первый слог.

Исключения. У глаголов *класть, красть и красться, пасть, упасть, слать, послать, стлать* ударение в форме женского рода прошедшего времени остаётся на основе:
*клАла, крАла, крАлась, пАла, упАла, слАла, послАла, стлАла.*

Также не следует забывать, что в глаголах совершенного вида в форме прошедшего времени приставка *вы-* имеет свойство перетягивать на себя ударение: *вЫглянул-вЫглянула, вЫнюхал-вЫнюхала, вЫчесал-вЫчесала и т. п.*

Comment: *>> Также не следует забывать, что приставка вы- принимает ударение на себя во всех формах глагола.* ВыглЯдывать, вынЮхивать, вычёсывать, выходИть и т.д.

Comment: а разъела, раздолбала, разобщила?

Answer (score 2):

Я посмотрел в Викисловарь (и Вам советую): [разобрала́](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

Также [Русский орфографический словарь онлайн](http://povto.ru/books/slovari/orfograficheskiy-slovar-online/orfograficheskii-slovar-online-bukva-r.htm): разорва́ть, -рву́, -рвёт; прош. -а́л, -ала́, -а́ло, -а́ло́. То же в словаре "[Русское словесное ударение](http://slovana.ru/slovari/zarva/russkoe-slovesnoe-udarenie-slovar-zarva_0432.htm)" под редакцией Зарвы.

Answer (score 1):

Есть контекст понимания действия. РазобрАла кровать - значит по частям ее получить и сложить в стороне. РазобралА - подготовила к сну, сняла покрывало и т.п.

Comment: как-то это не согласуется с имеющимися ответами